# Stock query result in variable and send email

Tags: mysql, bash, monitoring

I'm trying to monitor a specific port of a switch. I have to send email if my query returns a number >= 2.

I have tested my query and it works in Mysql CLI :

```
SELECT COUNT(message)
FROM devices, eventlog WHERE sysName = 'sysName' 
AND message = 'ifOperStatus: up -> down' 
AND datetime >= now() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE
```

This Query returns a correct value. So, I have decided to create a script that executes the query and get infos :

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

mysql -u DB_USER -p PASSWORD DB_NAME <<MY_QUERY

SELECT COUNT(message)
FROM devices, eventlog WHERE sysName = 'swysName' 
AND message = 'ifOperStatus: up -> down' 
AND datetime >= now() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE

MY_QUERY
```

When I execute this script in terminal, I got this:

```
librenms@librenms:/opt/librenms/scripts$ bash -x test1.sh
+ mysql -u DB_USER '-p PASSWORD' DB_NAME
COUNT(message)
0
```

Now I have to get query's value in a variable and test variable with an "if" in the script as :

```
....
if ($nb >= 2)
```

Then, if condition is true, send mail to alert admin.
I don't know how to get value in a variable and send by mail in bash script. If someone can help me...
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should get results of mysql query first:

```
RES = $(mysql -u DB_USER -p PASSWORD DB_NAME <<$MY_QUERY)
```

and then send it using:

```
echo $RES | mail -s "Information" email@email.com
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer . I will try it. An idea of how test $RES and send mail if test is true ?      Like if ($RES >= 2)